# How can I move my CSS slider at intervals?

Tags: html, css

I have got the following code that I am currently struggling with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

<head>

 
  <style type="text/css">
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

.slides {
  top: 0
  px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 840px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.nav label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

   opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: rgb(255,133,102);
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380%;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 left:90px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container" >
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/9999/9999/files/Pulpbar_presentation_slide_01.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/9999/9999/files/ice2.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
      <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
      <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to move to the next slider within a certain time. The .nav label seems to be the area of interest, but I was unfortunately not able to trigger it. Any ideas how that might work or any recommendations on what to read up on?

Comment: In CSS you cannot trigger events, nor can you manipulate DOM. Contrary to what you have been told, JavaScript is primarily a good thing and pretty much the proper way to go when you want this type of functionality. Don't get me wrong, when you want pure CSS solutions I'm a good person to ask for it. But this doesn't mean I don't use JavaScript or that I try to replace it with CSS. Some things should be done via CSS, some others via JS. What you ask for should be done in JavaScript.

Comment: @isherrwood - FatTwin probably means 'slideshow' ... this seems to be an pure css attempt to slideshow as far I can read it ...

Comment: @FatTwin - I looked into my crystal ball and asked it what possible you might want, cos you sure did not write it clear ... The ball says 'Use css transitions with delays!' ... so I guess you try consume that info and then search for blogs and articles such as this one ...

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu - you know, we do not live in ideal world ... for example, there are developers on one side and there are users and clients on the other side of the table. All my clients always want fallback to noscript version of the web, but require modern interactivity and effects and possibly that the app looks and feel the same with and without. Hard to explain them this is very often heavy lifting with potential of breaking both hands and legs ... and there are developers, usually php lovers, who fight bravely against JS and promote pure css. Pure css is hence a vaild option for many.

Comment: It's not hard to explain at all, @Emocuc. It's a crystal clear economical equation: *"Option a) is X amount of hours, option b) is Y amount of hours. It's your call, Sir!"*. Just make sure either way it's worth your time and effort. And, when dealing at this level, you don't depend on a SO answer to provide a noscript solution.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - That is business approach, mine is different "What can I do for you to make you happy? OH, you want facebook without server and written in Lisp? Great, lets talk about that..." ... actually, many people do not care that strongly about money ... but that is different story ... pure css is real thing and if one asks for pure css solution and it is possible, you should at least know how to approach that from technical point of view ... it might actually help you to optimise your css structure in other projects as well ...

Comment: @Emocuc: I am not a programmer, just an analyst and try to set up this Shopify store. I am doing my best in learning it all quickly, but I don't seem to get anything Javascript related running for some reason, hence the pure css solutions. I did in fact mean slideshow. In the current form you can only navigate to the next and previous slide by clicking on side bars. I was trying to add a timed trigger to the next picture in line if that makes sense. I came across css transitions but these don't seem to trigger an event by itself.

Comment: + @AndreiGheorghiu ^

Comment: perhaps you can use css keyframe animations on every slide looped infinitely with certain delay. but I did not get the part about JS - sounds like you would use JS, but you are having some issues - do you want to rather get JS solution working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the discussion under the question is getting somewhat extensive, here is a summary of what your options are.

**VOCABULARY / USE CASE**

This is something I struggle with constantly myself -> name technicalities with correct terms. In your case you asked about slider with events, which generally is an input element, something like `<input type="range">`, but in a fact you meant 'slideshow'. This confused some user, who since left this thread. But anyway, always try to research your use case first before you post your question and update it accordingly if you get language-related comments under it. Fair enough, we all know now that this question is about css slideshow, or as others would call it 'carousel'. Also, you could have pinned some images to suggest what is the desired result of your code to avoid boring explanation.

**PURE CSS**

You have asked for a pure CSS slideshow. This can be done and has been done frequently. [In this blog post](https://corpocrat.com/2015/12/09/20-cool-pure-css-sliders-without-jqueryjavascript/) you can see some of the notorious examples that you can easily study and even bring directly into your code. Since your question and comment suggest that you are not really advanced coder, I would recommend you study general css first, then the examples of slideshows.

**CONSIDER READY-MADE ELEMENTS**

I am not sure what is the issue with JS at your side, but it sounds like you are not avoiding JS on purpose. If you are starting with coding and you just want to bring some page up. It might be a lot easier for you to use some kind of library of pre-styled and pre-coded components that you just implement into your page. There is huge amount of these ready-made components, often called 'material', such as [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). Probably the most popular is [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) -> [here is Bootstrap's carousel example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and this thorough answer. I am currently trying to pinpoint the JS issue with Shopify's support team, so hopefully that's all figured out soon, since ultimately JS solutions seem much more attractive in regards to browser support and such. I will take your advice to heart and try to be more thorough in my initial research to be able to express my issues more clearly. Thanks again for all the good information to go off of :)